# Finding dual lattice of $(\Bbb N_0,\text{divisibility})$ and showing its isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, lattice-orders

I'm trying to understand the concept of dual lattices by solving a problem:

> Prove that the dual lattice of $(\Bbb N_0,\text{divisibility})$ is
>   isomorphic with the lattice $\text{sub}(\Bbb Z)$ where $(\Bbb Z,+)$ is
>   the group of all integers.

I'm not really sure how the dual lattice is found for lattices like these (in order theory). I only know the dual lattice definition (in group theory):

> The dual of a lattice $\wedge$ is the set $\hat{\wedge}$ of all
>   vectors $\mathbf{x}\in\text{span}(\wedge)$ such that $\langle
>  \mathbf{x,y} \rangle$ is an integer for $\mathbf{y}\in\wedge$

which doesn't seem to be applicable here.

Any idea how to find the dual lattice and then show the isomorphism?

Answer (score 4):

We obtain the dual lattice if we simply reverse its partial order, or equivalently, if we exchange the lattice operations $\land$ and $\lor$.

For the statement, you basically have to prove that all subgroups of $\Bbb Z$ are of the form $n\Bbb Z$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: You mean I have to replace the partial order relation from "divides" to "is divisible by"?

Comment: Yes. But you don't have to, just observe that the ordering is reversed by the mapping you define.